# Convert hierarchical index to column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the input data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
        "author" : ["A","B","A","A","C","B"] , 
        "topic" : ["cat", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dog", "dog"] } )
df1
```

```
    author  topic
0   A   cat
1   B   dog
2   A   dog
3   A   cat
4   C   dog
5   B   dog
```

I'm using group by as follows

```
g1 = df1.groupby('author')['topic'].value_counts()
```

```
author  topic
A       cat      2
        dog      1
B       dog      2
C       dog      1
```

What I'm looking to achieve is this

```
author  cat   dog 
A       2     1
B       0     2
C       0     1
```

Basically, need to convert the second-order of index in hierarchical indexing to columns. How can I do that?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df1['author'],df1['topic'])` - you can also just use crosstab or pivot_table here

Comment: See section on `cross tabulation`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe/47152692#47152692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) here:

```
df = df1.groupby('author')['topic'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df1['author'], df1['topic'])
```